# Access individual points in Shapely MultiPoint

Tags: python, shapely

I am working with the Shapely library in Python. I find the intersection of two lines, the return value is given as a MultiPoint object.

How do I deconstruct the object to get the individual points in the intersection?

Here is the code:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
a = LineString([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)])
b = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)])
x = a.intersection(b)
```

Output:

```
print(x) 
MULTIPOINT (1 1, 2 0)
```

So, in this case, I'd be looking for a way to extract the intersection points (1,1) and (2,0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can index the resulting MultiPoint:

```
>>> str(x)
'MULTIPOINT (1 1, 2 0)'
>>> print(len(x))
2
>>> print(x[0].x)
1.0
>>> print(x[0].y)
1.0
```

If you want a new list with the coordinates, you can use:

```
>>> [(p.x, p.y) for p in x]
[(1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 0.0)]
```

Comment: What about if there are 3 intersection points, you obtain a MultiPoint and a LineString?

Comment: I have installed `shapely==2.0.0` and `MultiPoint` is not iterable or subscriptable now. :/

Comment: Try x.geoms[0] (see [here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.MultiPoint.html) )

Answer (score 2):

Use `.geoms`:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
a = LineString([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)])
b = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0)])

multipoint = a.intersection(b)
print(multipoint)
#MULTIPOINT (2 0, 1 1)
points = [p for p in multipoint.geoms]
print(points)
#[<POINT (2 0)>, <POINT (1 1)>]
```